# How to implement (bubbling) validation events for custom WPF control

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml

I have developed a custom WPF control:

```
public partial class PercentTextbox : UserControl, IDataErrorInfo, INotifyDataErrorInfo
```

And I put that control inside a `UserControl` along with some other controls:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControlContainingPercentTextboxAndStuff" DataContext="Something" ...>
  <Grid>
    <mycontrols:PercentTextbox Value="{Binding MyPercentageValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" ... />
    <TextBox ... />
    <mycontrols:PercentTextbox ... />
    <TextBox ... />
    <TextBox ... />
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And finally, I use another wrapping `UserControl` to show the above `UserControl` as dialog:

```
<UserControl ...>
  <Grid>
    <local:UserControlContainingPercentTextboxAndStuff ... />
    <Button x:Name="SaveButton" Content="Save" ... />
    <Button x:Name="CancelButton" Content="Cancel" ... />
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In the code behind of the latter, I want to subscribe to all validation errors, and disable the save button if there are errors.

```
Validation.AddErrorHandler(this, (sender, e) =>
{
  SaveButton.IsEnabled = false;
  Debug.WriteLine(e.Error);
});
```

I was thinking, that if I'd implement `IDataErrorInfo` or `INotifyDataErrorInfo`, WPF would somehow magically handle stuff for me, and create a ValidationError event (which would bubble up to the `UserControl`. But clearly, I am missing something essential here.

My question is: What do I have to implement in my custom control `PercentTextbox` in order to use it in arbitrary places and still get some kind of bubbling-up validation information which I can use in a container `UserControl` (e.g. to disable the SaveButton).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IDataErrorInfo` and `INotifyDataErrorInfo` are supposed to be implemented on the model side, not on the UI side. Then you can set the `ValidatesOnDataErrors = True` or `ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors = True` options on your `Binding`s, so that the binding validation system jumps in. There are some good tutorials on the web about that. It's not the UI telling that something is invalid, but the data this UI represents.

The data validation concept is tightly coupled with the data bindings. If you want your user control to perform its own "UI" validation, use [the coercing and validation callbacks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-callbacks-and-validation) of the dependency properties. However, this has nothing to do with the data validation of the binding system. The validation callback will cause the property system to throw an exception that you can handle as you wish (e.g. you can use the `ExceptionValidationRule` for your bindings).

Take a look on the `Validation.Error` attached event [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.error%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (which you're actually trying to observe by calling `Validation.AddErrorHandler`). It states:

> Occurs when the bound element runs into a validation error, **but only
>   for bindings with the NotifyOnValidationError value set to true**.

So you have two options now:

- implement the validation on the model side and set up your bindings accordingly (you have to do this for each binding to your custom control's properties)
- use the dependency property validation callbacks